# c++ Alternative implementation to avoid shifting between RAM and SWAP memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a program, that uses dynamic programming to calculate some information. The problem is, that theoretically the **used memory grows exponentially**. Some filters that I use limit this space, but for a big input they also can't avoid that my **program runs out of RAM - Memory**.

The program is running on 4 threads. When I run it with a really big input I noticed, that at some point the **program starts to use the swap memory**, because my RAM is not big enough. The consequence of this is, that my **CPU-usage decreases from about 380% to 15% or lower**.

There is only one variable that uses the memory which is the following datastructure:

**Edit (added type) with [CLN library](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/):**

```
class My_Map {

    typedef std::pair<double,short> key;
    typedef cln::cl_I value;

public: 
    tbb::concurrent_hash_map<key,value>* map;

    My_Map()  { map = new tbb::concurrent_hash_map<myType>(); }
    ~My_Map() { delete map; }

    //some functions for operations on the map
};
```

In my main program I am using this datastructure as globale variable:

```
My_Map* container = new My_Map();
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to avoid the shifting of memory between SWAP and RAM? I thought pushing all the memory to the `Heap` would help, but it seems not to. So I don't know if it is possible to maybe fully use the swap memory or something else. Just this shifting of memory cost much time. The CPU usage decreases dramatically.

Comment: Is your program perhaps suffering from memory leaks? I see you use the memory leak operator (`new`) instead of automatic memory management, so maybe you are doing that in a lot of other places as well.

Comment: Maybe reducing number of threads can reduce memory consumption 4fold? When the problem shifts to memory-bound from cpu-bound, more threads decrease performance.

Comment: Buying more ram may help too.

Comment: A garbage collector might be a good idea. @user2079303 depending on the input also more RAM wouldn't help.

Comment: Garbage collector is not magic. When you use `new`, you **MUST** use `delete`.

Comment: Store less stuff. DP is about trading storage for less recalculation, but if you start swapping, some recalculation would be cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 1 Gig of RAM and you have a program that uses up 2 Gb RAM, then you're going to have to find somewhere else to store the excess data.. obviously. The default OS way is to swap but the alternative is to manage your own 'swapping' by using a memory-mapped file.

You open a file and allocate a virtual memory block in it, then you bring pages of the file into RAM to work on. The OS manages this for you for the most part, but you should think about your memory usage so not to try to keep access to the same blocks while they're in memory if you can.

On Windows you use CreateFileMapping(), on Linux you use mmap(), on Mac you use [mmap()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html).

Comment: Ok thank you I will have a look at this. Actually I am using mac OS, but I think this will work for mac, too. Does this not somehow make the access slow?

Comment: yes, it makes access slow - but you cannot put a quart into a pint pot. Apart from buying more RAM, you have to manage your resource limitations.

Comment: Yes, it's very slow compared to RAM. But it's your fault for creating algorithm that uses more RAM than available. Focus on decreasing memory consumption.

Answer (score 3):

The OS is working properly - it doesn't distinguish between stack and heap when swapping - it pages you whatever you seem not to be using and loads whatever you ask for.

There are a few things you could try:

- consider whether `myType` can be made smaller - e.g. using `int8_t` or even width-appropriate bitfields instead of `int`, using pointers to pooled strings instead of worst-case-length character arrays, use offsets into arrays where they're smaller than pointers etc..  If you show us the type maybe we can suggest things.

  - think about your paging - if you have many objects on one memory page (likely 4k) they will need to stay in memory if any one of them is being used, so try to get objects that will be used around the same time onto the same memory page - this may involve hashing to small arrays of related `myType` objects, or even moving all your data into a packed array if possible (binary searching can be pretty quick anyway).  Naively used hash tables tend to flay memory because similar objects are put in completely unrelated buckets.
  - serialisation/deserialisation with compression is a possibility: instead of letting the OS swap out full myType memory, you may be able to proactively serialise them into a more compact form then deserialise them only when needed
- consider whether you need to process all the data simultaneously... if you can batch up the work in such a way that you get all "group A" out of the way using less memory then you can move on to "group B"

---

UPDATE now you've posted your actual data types...

Sadly, using `short` might not help much because `sizeof key` needs to be 16 anyway for alignment of the `double`; if you don't need the precision, you could consider `float`?  Another option would be to create an array of separate maps...

```
tbb::concurrent_hash_map<double,value> map[65536];
```

You can then index to `map[my_short][my_double]`.  It could be better or worse, but is easy to try so you might as well benchmark....

For `cl_I` a 2-minute dig suggests the data's stored in a [union](http://code.woboq.org/kde/include/cln/object.h.html#cln%3a%3acl_gcobject) - presumably `word` is used for small values and one of the pointers when necessary... that looks like a pretty good design - hard to improve on.

If numbers tend to repeat a lot (a big if) you could experiment with e.g. keeping a registry of big `cl_I`s with a bi-directional mapping to packed integer ids which you'd store in `My_Map::map` - fussy though.  To explain, say you get 987123498723489 - you `push_back` it on a `vector<cl_I>`, then in a `hash_map<cl_I, int>` set `[987123498723489` to that index (i.e. `vector.size() - 1`).  Keep going as new numbers are encountered.  You can always map from an `int` id back to a `cl_I` using direct indexing in the `vector`, and the other way is an `O(1)` amortised hash table lookup.

Comment: I added my type; already thought about this and used short for the second part of the `std::pair`.

Comment: @alexvii: sounds tough - I added some to my answer.  Is there any particular pattern in order you generate/encounter keys?  Some natural way to know that a variety of `cl_I` will be accessed in order?